# My Book Essential 3.0 RPM

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I just bought a WD My Book Essential 3.0 with 1TB and USB 3.0. The code for the product is WDBACW0010HBK.

How can I find out what RPM it has? There is no mention in the manual and the official site and other sites return either no results or conflicting ones.

Does anyone know for sure? Or is there a way I can test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at:

http://www.span.com/product_info.php?products_id=33123

+

http://www.memoryx.net/wdbacw0010hbks.html

They show it is a 7200RPM External Drive.